# How to use DrawTransparentBitmap() in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, tbitmap

Just trying to figure out how to use DrawTransparent in C++ Builder to draw a bitmap or tbitmap with an alpha channel so that the drawn image is semi-transparent with the background image.

I looked all over the place and on this site but can't find anything other than a note that this as well as DrawTransparentBitmap exists..

In the help it is listed as follows:

```
virtual void __fastcall DrawTransparent(TCanvas* ACanvas, const 
System::Types::TRect &Rect, System::Byte Opacity);
```

However there are no code examples.  The compiler doesn't recognize the procedure name and it does not appear as a method of tbitmap...

I am still new to C++ and I could really use some help with this...

Comment: If the compiler doesn't even recognize the function, using it is likely to be seriously problematic. My immediate advice would be to consider using [`AlphaBlend`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-alphablend) instead.

Comment: `DrawTransparent` is a protected method so you can't call it directly, but perhaps this works `destination_bitmap->Canvas->Draw(0, 0, source_bitmap->Picture->Graphic, 50);` You may need to do `source_bitmap->Transparent = true;` too. Haven't tested it myself.

Comment: I'm sure I am doing something wrong..  There are nuances to C++ that I still don't get..  There is probably some way to declare it or something...  It is supposed to be a part of the existing graphics system, or it appears so - like StretchDraw() so I figured it would be easier to integrate...  But I will look into the AlphaBlend, thanks.

Comment: What is a protected method?  Thanks all info helps...

Comment: There's a good description of what a protected member (method or variable) is here: [access specifiers @ cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access).

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo:  That seems to work!  You ROCK....  Post it as an answer if you like so I can give you the credit...

Comment: @Jim great, answer added :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DrawTransparent` is a protected method so you can't call it directly, but this should work:

```
// opacity 50 
destination_bitmap->Canvas->Draw(0, 0, source_bitmap->Picture->Graphic, 50);
```

You may need to do `source_bitmap->Transparent = true;` too.

Comment: This does draw a blend....:)  Just need to get the new bitmap to work with transparent color, so far doesn't want to...even using Transparent = True and specifying a color...